# Program not outputting data correctly

Tags: java, queue, output, intersection

I am working on a class assignment that has us create a system to simulate vehicles at an intersection. We are to assume that there is one lane going in each of four directions, with stoplights facing each direction. We have to vary the arrival average of vehicles in each direction and the frequency of the light changes to view the "behavior" of the intersection.

I gave my best attempt at the assignment, but still being new to Java I seem to have made a mistake that I am taking a very long time trying to figure out. Basically, my outputs at the bottom of the program do not output anything.

I am also currently stuck assuming that the outputs will output what I am desiring them to, which obviously would require the rest of my code to be sound.

That being said, if anyone can spot my error that is preventing my code from outputting everything, or anything in addition that catches your eye, then I would be very appreciative.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Intersection
{
private final static int PROCESS = 3;
private final static int SIM_LENGTH = 1000;

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
          Car car = new Car();

          Deque<Car> carQueue = new LinkedList<Car>();

          int delayTotal = 0, carArrival, lightChange = 0, switchCount = 0, changeCount = 0;
          double carCount;
          boolean even = false;
          String lightColor, green = null, red = null;


              Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

              System.out.println("Enter in a car arrival interval between 1 and 5 seconds." + "\n");
              carArrival = scan.nextInt();

              if (!(carArrival < 6 && carArrival > 0))
                  System.out.println("Enter a valid time." + "\n");

              Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

              System.out.println("Enter in a traffic light duration between 5 and 10 seconds." + "\n");
              lightChange = sc.nextInt();


              if (!(lightChange < 11 && lightChange > 4))
                  System.out.println("Enter a valid time." + "\n");

              //add a car to the queue every [carArrival] seconds
              for (int i = 0; i < SIM_LENGTH; i+= carArrival)
                  {
                    carQueue.add(car);
                  }


              //Develop a way for the program to know that SIM_LENGTH has
              //counted 'lightChange' seconds.
              //Count each time lightChange occurs

              for (int i = 0; i < SIM_LENGTH; i++)
              {
                  if (i % lightChange == 0)
                  {
                     changeCount++;
                  }
              }


            //Assuming light starts as red, every time the preceding count increases by 1,
            //switch lightColor.
            //if count % 2 == 0, return green light; else red light

              if (changeCount % 2 == 0)
              {
                  even = true;
              }


              if (even)
                  {
                  lightColor = green;
                  }
              else
                  {
                  lightColor = red;
                  }

              while (lightColor == green)
              {
                    //remove a car from the queue every [PROCESS] seconds
                    //(PROCESS is time to pass intersection)

                      for (int i = 0; i < SIM_LENGTH; i+= PROCESS)
                      {
                          carQueue.remove(car);
                      }

                      //I increment 'switchCount so I can use it as a divisor
                      //for delayTotal to find the delayAverage

                      switchCount++;
              }
              //Trying to increment delay time (cars are immobilized by red light)
              delayTotal += lightChange;


          //carCount Example:
          //lightChange = 6; PROCESS = 3; switchCount =166.7 times
          //carCount = 333.4 cars; obviously I need it to a whole number

          carCount = (lightChange / PROCESS) * switchCount; 

          int delayAverage = delayTotal/switchCount;
          int stranded = carQueue.size();

          System.out.println("Cars across: " + carCount);
          System.out.println("Delay (tot): " + delayTotal);
          System.out.println("Delay (avg): " + delayAverage);
          System.out.println("Number stranded: " + stranded);

   }
```

}

Comment: My guess is that it's still waiting for input, which is why it isn't outputting anything.  If you want to verify this, try hitting Enter once or twice and isee if your output starts showing up.  Using two `Scanners` on `System.in` could screw up the input mechanism.   You only need one.  Get rid of the second one.

Comment: Side note: if the user enters an invalid value for `carArrival`, you tell him to enter a valid value, but then you don't loop back to ask for another one.  You need to put that in a `while` loop.